# Cannot allocate a vector in R

Tags: r, memory

```
test=ldply(list.files(path="C:/rcsv",pattern="csv",full.names=TRUE),function(filename) {
dum=read.csv(filename)
dum$filename=filename
return(dum)
})
```

**Error: cannot allocate vector of size 19.2 Mb**

I have **5 .csv** files with **1 million** entries each . Now I want to read everything in to a data frame and perform some calculations but I am not able to do that because it does not read the files . How can I solve this  ?

Comment: I suspect it's loading a lot more data than you think. Can you add `print(filename)` and `print(str(dum))` to the anonymous function and include the output in your question?

Comment: I think it means it cannot allocate **another** chunck of size 19.2Mb.

Comment: -1 Memory usage is discussed in `?read.csv`. Warnings are given, and solutions are provided.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I know that's given but couldn't understand how would I solve my own thing . Just reading that didnt help me nor any other websites , so I posted the question

Comment: Sorry, no sympathy here. From `?read.csv`: "These functions can use a surprising amount of memory when reading large files. There is extensive discussion in the ['R Data Import/Export' manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html), supplementing the notes here. ... Less memory will be used if `colClasses` is specified... Using `nrows`, even as a mild over-estimate, will help memory usage." You don't appear to have tried any of those suggested solutions.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Not here for your sympathy please. Much more important things to do than this

Comment: Is it really that hard to understand adding `nrows = 1.1e6` to your `read.csv` call? Really? Saying you have "much more important things to do" is not a good way to get help from people who also have much more important things to do.

Comment: Thanks but its not working for me . I will figure out a way. So if you think that helping on a question which is optional is like giving sympathy then it was too costly for me . I totally understand your time . Thanks for helping .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest answer: Purchase more RAM.  If you work in R with large datasets often, it's worth it.  If you don't have enough memory to load your files, you may not have enough to manipulate them as you want either.

Let's assume that you could hold this data in RAM and manipulate it as you wish so that reading it in is your only problem.  The comments to your question have provided some ideas.  You could also use `scan()` to read your file instead of `read.csv`.  It requires a little more setup but is faster and relatively memory friendly.

There are several packages available to help people whose data is too large for memory.  The one I'm familiar with (though I haven't used it in years thanks to falling RAM prices) is `filehash`.  This will store your data on disk instead of RAM but you still interact with it the same way.  It will be slower, but likely resolve your problem.

```
library(filehash)
dbCreate('tmp.db')
dbhandle <- dbInit('tmp.db')
db <- db2env(dbhandle)    
db$test <- ldply(list.files(path="C:/rcsv",pattern="csv",full.names=TRUE),
function(filename) {
  db$dum <- read.csv(filename)
  db$dum$filename <- filename
  return(dum)
})
```

I don't know whether this approach has been deprecated, but I believe it still works.  I'm not sure to what extent `ldply()` will put temporary stuff in RAM.  If this fails you could instead create a list inside of `db`, read each of the files into the list in a `for` loop and then rbind them together yourself.

Another approach would be maybe to create an sqlite database and use `read.csv.sql()` from the sqldf package to put everything in there and then bind them.  Then at the end you can read the final dataframe out.

Comment: filehash is not available for my version of R but the second method looks good . Thanks